# How can i use bangla font as a string value in android

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-widget

how can i use bangla font in a android app as a string value in my string.xml file and also read in my UI.Advance thanks to answer

Answer (score 10):

First open `assets` folder and create a new folder named `font` and then put `Rupali.ttf` in the `font`folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/DefaultFontText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Here is some text." />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CustomFontText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="ডিরেক্টর মমনক(!?) করতেছি অন্তত ঘড়িটা যেন বানাতে পারি আমি চেষ্টা করছি">
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And,

```
package com.amader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fonts extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "font/Rupali.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
        tv.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Shortcoming: All bangla combined words does not work properly. If anybody has the solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the process given below:

create folder named assets under app folder

create folder named fonts under assets folder

now put your desire bangla font file like durga.ttf or otf in fonts folder

Now go where you declare your textview and put this code:

```
yourTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Durga.ttf"));
```